how to pass custom args in hilt viewModel android
Screen(AppScreens.InfoScreen.route) { navBackStackEntry ->
    val viewModel = hiltViewModel<ProfileDisplayScreenViewModel>()
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
      viewModel.setUpId(navBackStackEntry.getInt()!!)
    }
    ProfileDisplayScreen(uiState, viewModel.interActor)
}

i don't want to use LaunchedEffect and i want to pass args directly is this possible ?
if yes then how ?

Does this answer your question? How to pass arguments to ViewModel from Fragment and inject dependencies at the same time?

no this is not what i want. below given answer is correct for me

Yes, you can pass arguments directly to your ViewModel without using LaunchedEffect. Here’s how you can achieve this using Hilt's SavedStateHandle and the Navigation Component.
class ProfileDisplayScreenViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
      private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
      // other dependencies
) : ViewModel() {
 val uiState = // Your state handling logic

    init {
        val id =
            savedStateHandle.get<Int>("id") ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("ID is required")
        setUpId(id)
    }

    fun setUpId(id: Int) {
         // Your logic to set up the ID
    }
}

When navigating to your screen, pass the argument like this:
navController.navigate("info_screen/$id")

Define the route in your NavHost to accept the argument.
NavHost(navController, startDestination = "start_screen") {
composable("info_screen/{id}")
) { navBackStackEntry ->
    val viewModel: ProfileDisplayScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel(navBackStackEntry)
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    
    ProfileDisplayScreen(uiState, viewModel.interActor)
   }
}


hello brother, how can i do same with koin as i am on new project with kmm so i am using koin now so can we do the same as hilt in koin?, there is some documentation about it but i can't understand how to implement this
